# Prevent Yoast from removing the canonical tag if robots meta tag is set to noindex

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using Yoast on a staging site and I want to have a canonical URL that points to the primary domain.

So that *staging.whatever.com* uses canonical *whatever.com*

I am replacing the canonical tag using the `wpseo_canonical` filter.

```
add_filter('wpseo_canonical', 'force_canonical_domain_replace');
```

Where the force_canonical_domain_replace() does the replacement. It works fine.

I also set the meta robots tag to noindex, nofollow. Doing:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_robots', function( $robots ) {

   return 'noindex, nofollow';

} );
```

But it seems that Yoast automatically removes the canonical tag **when it detects noindex in the meta robots content**. How can I prevent that?

This is how I am doing the whole thing:

```
// Replace domain for any URL
add_filter('wpseo_canonical', 'force_canonical_domain_replace');
function force_canonical_domain_replace($url){

    $current_site_domain = whatever_get_current_domain();
    if('whatever.com' == $current_site_domain){
        return $url;
    }

    // Replace current domain with whatever.com in all urls
    return str_replace($current_site_domain, 'whatever.com', $url);

}

// Make sure that meta robots uses noindex, nofollow if we are not in whatever.com
add_filter( 'wpseo_robots', function( $robots ) {

    if('whatever.com' == whatever_get_current_domain()){
        return $robots;
    }

    // Replace string entirely to avoid issues
    return 'index, follow';

} );

// Helper function to safely get the current domain
function whatever_get_current_domain(){
   $parsed = parse_url(home_url());
   return $parsed['host'];
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, sorry. WP 5.8.3, Yoast 18.1 and 29 plugins active in total. The second example (`add_filter('wpseo_robots', ..`) works and I see `<meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow' />` on all pages. Did you try deactivating other plugins and see if the behavior changes?

Comment: @kero - Hmm... do you see meta and canonical, both tags, on all pages?

Comment: Can you add the full code to both? Only tried with the `wpseo_robots` filter.

Comment: @kero Updated the question with the whole code. Whatever.com is the primary domain... and xxxxxx.whatever.com would be anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and the original question is: "How do I block crawlers from indexing my staging site?"

Staging and production should be as close as similar. Having changes in code would be a big "no no" for me (except for some environment variables, e.g. setting `WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE` or db credentials).

Instead, I would suggest setting up the webserver to [serve the `X-Robots-Tag` with `noindex`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag#xrobotstag). There [was some discussion which takes preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930932/precedence-of-x-robots-tag-header-vs-robots-meta-tag) if you have both (`X-Robots-Tag` and `<meta name="robots" />`), but in my experience it suffices to have `X-Robots-Tag: none` to not have the sites indexed, even if their own `<meta name="robots" />` differs.

- [How to set `X-Robots-Tag` on apache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393151/add-x-robots-tag-to-apache-config)
- [How to set `X-Robots-Tag` on NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077140/nginx-rule-to-add-x-robots-tag-header/35893590)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help and wisdom. In this case, someone asked me to do this and even though I will discuss this with them, I am still looking for a solution in the stated way. But this is still very helpul.